# How to solve $tx'(t) = (2t^2 + 1)x(t) + t^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that there is a unique solution of the differential equation 
$$
tx'(t) = (2t^2 + 1)x(t) + t^2
$$
for $t > 0$. Furthermore, show this solution has a finite limit as $t \rightarrow +\infty$, and compute this limit.

I am preparing for an entrance exam and this is one of the exercises I could practice with. The only problem is that the last time I did something with differential equations is years ago. So I'd be happy if the solution could contain general tips and tricks.

What I tried: I tried general functions to see if they work, but without success. I also tried assuming the function was equal to its power series. I managed to calculate the coefficients in the power series but what I got out of it was definitely not convergent for $t \rightarrow \infty$ so something must be wrong there.

**EDIT:** Using an integrating factor, I was able to find that for any choice of $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ the function
$$
f_{t_0} = te^{t^2}\int_{t_0}^t e^{-x^2}dx
$$
satisfies the differential equation:
\begin{align*}
f' &= (te^{t^2})' \cdot \int_{t_0}^t e^{-x^2}dx + te^{t^2} \cdot e^{-t^2}\\
&= (2t^2e^{t^2} + e^{t^2}) \int_{t_0}^t e^{-x^2}dx + t\\
&= (2t + \frac{1}{t}) te^{t^2} \int_{t_0}^t e^{-x^2}dx + t\\
&= (2t + \frac{1}{t}) f + t
\end{align*}

However, this solution is not unique, as we can vary $t_0$. Moreover, the limit as $t \rightarrow \infty$ does not seem to exist!

Is the question incorrect?

Comment: @Amzoti , yes I just rechecked. It is question number 10 from http://mathematics.ceu.edu/sites/mathematics.ceu.hu/files/attachment/basicpage/18/entranceexam2011.pdf if you want to take a look.

Comment: This seems to be a simple 1d problem that you can solve with an integrating factor.

Comment: @Amzoti I just learned about the integrating factor, thanks for the reference! Is the thing I stumbled upon what you meant with "something seems wrong"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your work is correct but the way you've presented the solution makes it hard to see how to get finiteness. Rewriting your ODE, we have

$$x'(t) - \frac{2t^2+1}{t}x(t) = t.$$

The integrating factor is then $e^{-\int (2t+\frac{1}{t})\,dt} = e^{-t^2-\log(t)} = \frac{1}{t}e^{-t^2}.$ Then your ODE becomes

$$\left(\frac{1}{t}e^{-t^2}x(t)\right)' = e^{-t^2}.$$

Integrating both sides from $t_0$ to $t$, we get

$$\frac{1}{t}e^{-t^2}x(t) - \frac{1}{t_0}e^{-t_0^2}x(t_0) = \int_{t_0}^t e^{-x^2}\,dx \Longrightarrow x(t) = cte^{t^2}+ te^{t^2}\int_{t_0}^t e^{-x^2}\,dt.$$

(I've just set $c = \frac{1}{t_0}e^{-t_0^2}x(t_0)$ since this is just a fixed constant.)

In order for $\lim_{x\to\infty}x(t)$ to be finite, you need that $te^{t^2}\left(c+\int_{t_0}^t e^{-x^2}\,dx\right)$ goes to a finite value. Since the term we factored out ($t e^{t^2}$) goes to infinity, the only way for the overall term to go to a finite value is if the term within parentheses to go to zero. Can you see how to proceed?

Comment: Yes I guess $c$ should be $\sqrt(\pi)/2$ if we set $t_0 = 0$. I am trying out different approaches now to calculate this limit, but without success so far..

Comment: Whoops I meant $-\sqrt(\pi)/2$ of course..

Comment: with a lot of work I was able to show the limit is bounded from above by 1/2 (or -1/2, I lost track of the sign). Since the function we're taking the limit of is increasing, this shows the limit exists.. But I am using $t \cdot \int_{t}^{t+k} e^{-x^2}dx < \int_{t}^{t+k} t \cdot e^{-x^2}dx $ and I cannot see any other way to do it without this strict inequality.. Could you give another hint on how to proceed?

Comment: You have the right idea but you're overthinking it. Let $c = \int_{t_0}^{\infty} e^{-t^2}\,dt$.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant when saying $c = \sqrt(\pi)/2$. Still am clueless on how to proceed, I must shamefully admit.. Thanks for your help in any case! :)